# Hiding UINavigationItem's bar button

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I have added a `BarButton` item to the left of the `nav.bar` through Interface Builder and in the code I want this only to show in my table view's edit mode. But I didn't find any hidden property to set the `leftBarButtonItem` (like: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.hidden = YES`).

I can only set `enabled` property. Anybody know how to control the hide and show property of the `leftBarButtonItem`, please help.

Answer (score 63):

This works I tried it myself

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: In some instances setting it to nil didn't work for me, but setting hidesBackButton to YES worked! Thanks.

Comment: Setting to nil will let navigationItem follow its default behavior, which is to show a back button if you're in a subview of a navigation controller, that's why you also need to set hidesBackButton to true if you don't want anything to show ever

Comment: I'm finding that this doesn't work at `viewDidLoad` time, but does work at `viewWillAppear:` time.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure the only way to "hide" it is to nil it out.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Though it's not a perfect answer to your question, since that basically gets rid of your button instead of hiding it. You'll either have to recreate it or keep your original button around and simply set the leftBarButtonItem back to your UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was also thinking of such an approach if I can't actually hide.

Answer (score 6):

I have a easy function to make this.
I have a navigation like this.
[image: Navigation Bar]
It comes form Interface Builder, it has a background image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var memberBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
```

you can hide/show it by:

```
func hideMemberBtn() {
    memberBtn.isEnabled = false
    memberBtn.tintColor = UIColor.clear
}
func showMemberBtn() {
    memberBtn.isEnabled = true
    memberBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

It's easy but it work for me. You can change tintColor as you needed.
Hope for help :]

Comment: Good lord, this is by far the easiest way to get this to work

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
// Hide
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;

// Show
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.myBarButtonItem
```

The key is making sure that you have a **strong** reference to the button item before nilling `leftBarButtonItem`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 3):

I just created my own "hide" function show below:

```
- (void)hideClearButton:(BOOL)hide {

    if (hide) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                 initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Clear", @"Recents")
                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                 target:self action:@selector(clearAll:)];

    }
}
```

You can just call it like:

```
[self hideClearButton:YES]; //hide it
```

or

```
[self hideClearButton:NO];  //show it
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the documentation to suggest bar items have a hidden property.

Why not set

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

when the user isn't editing, then set

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = whateverBarButtonItem;
```

when the user is editing? This requires either re-creating the button each time or storing it for the duration of the view's lifecycle. Neither is terribly painful, but no, not nearly as easy as a .hidden property.

Comment: Neil beat me to it – exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:TRUE];
```

as there is no other way to hide it. so just disable it.

Answer (score 1):

To hide/disable

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:FALSE];
```

To show/enable

```
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:TRUE];
```

Comment: Fair enough they do. Just think sticking to objective-C syntax helps readability. In this case it's irrelevant I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well making it nil was not a option because i wanted to show it again and didnt want to create a button again.

so what i did was

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barButton =  (UIBarButtonItem *)self.navBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem;
 barButton.customView.hidden = true;//Hide
 barButton.customView.hidden = false;//Show
```

Works for me. (my leftBarButtonItem was created using customView)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *btnL = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:myView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func showOrHideButton() {
        isEnabled ? showButton() : hideButton()
    }

 func showButton() {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: self, action: #selector(action))
    }

    func hideButton() {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    }
```