# Different UIToolBar/UINavigatonBar when tapping UITextField

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Ok so I have a UINavbarController with Next and Back buttons in the toolbar using setLeftBarButtonItem and setRightBarButtonItem. I have a bunch of textfields in a tableview below that and when someone taps in the textfield I want to change the navbar to

a) remove or hide the Cancel and Save buttons 
b) add a done button to close the keyboard or datepicker

When using setRightBarButtonItem/setLeftBarButonItem I can't actually remove or hide the Cancel/Save buttons... only disable them.

So my question is how can I display a different UItoolBar when tapping in a textfield to display different buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why do you want to place another toolbar, when you have already one. Use the same buttons by changing the names of tool bar button.

steps to be taken care.

1. add `Delegate` to textfields. (So you can use textfield delegate methods to change the title name of buttons when textfield begins editing & ended.)

2.performing action on left & right button check for the condition.
i.e

```
UIBarButton *the_button = (UIBarButton *)sender;

if([[the_button.currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"Save"])
{
//perform some action
}

else 
{
//perform else condition
}
```

Comment: What if for example I had a Cancel and Save button in the navbar and when clicking into a textfield it displays a UIDatePicker at the bottom and I want to remove the Cancel button and change Save button to a done button... Save to Done is easy enough based on your example but Cancel cannot be removed right?

Comment: then you hide the cancel button. i.e self.navigationbar.leftBarbutton.hidden = YES;

Comment: hidden is not a property you can set on a leftBarButtonItem. There is only enabled (BOOL).

Comment: check with link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226294/hiding-uinavigationitems-bar-button