# Hide UINavigationItem in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, adbannerview

The code I wrote was working fine until I brought about a `BannerView` to show ads in the app. To bring the `BannerView` in all views I used the following code in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (IS_IPHONE()) {

        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    } else {

        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
        self.viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IpadViewController"];

    }
    self.navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.bannerViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.navigationController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.bannerViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But when I used this code a UINavigationItem appears on the top, hiding my actual controls.  I want to hide UINavigationItem, not just the buttons. I got the following links on googling.

- [Stack Overflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146406/hidding-uinavigationitem)
- [Stack Overflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226294/hiding-uinavigationitems-bar-button)

The first question doesn't have an answer and the answer to the second question doesn't solve my problem, because it is the UINavigationItem itself which I want to hide, not just the buttons. I tried setting the topBar to none in interface builder and tried using the following code:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

In the `viewDidLoad` but nothing helped a bit. When I comment off the following line from the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, the view is fine, but then the ad won't show up.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.bannerViewController;
```

What can be done to rectify this?

Comment: try `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: @arthan.v didn't help. And please note that I want the UINavigationItem to be hidden. The above code actually says it shouldn't be hidden.

Comment: try with `YES`.. i forgot to change.. now i changed it.

Comment: @arthan.v thanks very much. That solved my problem. Please post it as an answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide `navigationbar` use `navigationBarHidden` property. Like,

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

for you reference check,  [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBarHidden%5d)

if you want to animate your `navigationBar` while hiding, use

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]
```